# Check date format and covert in pyhton

Tags: python

I need to check the incoming date format from ADF and convert it accordingly using Databricks.
Below is the code I used:

```
if startDate == (startDate, "%Y-%m-%d")
    startDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate,"%Y-%m-%d")
elif startDate == (startDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
    startDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
else startDate == (startDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    startDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

But I get invalid syntax error.
Please help.

Comment: Put a`:` at the end of the if statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Issues

- You're missing `:` at the end of the `if/elif/else` statements

  ```
  if startDate == (startDate, "%Y-%m-%d"):
  ```
- You comparison is wrong, a `datetime` object will be never be equal to a tuple `(datetime, string)`, there not the same thing

#### Solutions

1. Use regexes to select the format

   ```py
    def to_datetime(value):
        formats = [
            (r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", "%Y-%m-%d"),
            (r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3,6}", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"),
            (r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
        ]
        for regex, dt_fmt in formats:
            if re.fullmatch(regex, value):
                return datetime.strptime(value, dt_fmt)
   ```
2. Use try/except block

   ```py
   def to_datetime(value):
        formats = ["%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"]
        for dt_fmt in formats:
            try:
                return datetime.strptime(value, dt_fmt)
            except:
                pass
   ```

---

```
print(to_datetime("2023-02-02"))  # 2023-02-02 00:00:00
print(to_datetime("2023-02-02T12:13:14.123"))  # 2023-02-02 12:13:14.123000
print(to_datetime("2023-02-02T12:13:14.123456"))  # 2023-02-02 12:13:14.123456
print(to_datetime("2023-02-02T12:13:14"))  # 2023-02-02 12:13:14
```

Answer (score -5):

There is a syntax error in your code on the first line of your conditional statement. Instead of using a double equal sign to compare startDate to a tuple of two elements, you should use the is keyword. Additionally, your else statement should not have a condition. Here is the corrected code:

**if startDate is (startDate, "%Y-%m-%d"):

```
startDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

elif startDate is (startDate, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"):

```
startDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

else:

```
startDateTime = datetime.strptime(startDate,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")**
```

Note that the is keyword is used for identity comparison, whereas the double equal sign == is used for value comparison. In this case, you want to compare the identity of startDate to the tuple (startDate, "%Y-%m-%d"), which contains the format string that you want to use for parsing the date.

Also, keep in mind that if startDate does not match any of the specified formats, you will get a ValueError when trying to convert it to a datetime object. You may want to add some error handling to your code to handle this case.

Comment: You are absolutly wrong, `is` is absolutly not the solution, it is AS wrong AS the ==

Comment: I'm suprised to see a new account coming at this exact moment to share to very wrong answer. Plus, you're giving details about how `is` should work without thinking that comparing a datetime to tuple won't work. Even chatgpt gave a better answer